# How to change other page's content using jQuery?

Tags: ajax

I have to explain this using an example. Suppose you have a website which sells some products. In your home page you have some items like banana, apple, juice etc. Now when we click on the card where the products is displayed it will take you to a registration page where you have to fill your data for delivery purposes. Now at the top of the form you want to show the name of the item that has been clicked in the home page. I have been trying it for the past few days but with no success. Please someone help.

Comment: You can store information in localstorage, for example

Comment: Please can you give examples of what you have tried.  If you can provide a minimum example of the problem in Codepen, jsbin etc or StackOverflow code snippet you'll probably get better help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LocalStorage to save the selected items and show it in the other page:
localStorage.setItem("productname", selectedname);
localStorage.getItem("productname");

Comment: You can save your selected item before you moved to the next page that has the form by this: localstorage. setItem(“variablename”,”selectedItem”). it will be stored in this variable: variablename.  Now where you want to display it: you can use only: localstorage.getItem(variablename). localstorage among your website pages.

Comment: You can use : document.getElementsByTagName (‘header’)to get the header tag and you can assign the innerHTML or seAttributes to whatever you want